# How to scale vertices in only top view but not impacting how they look in front view?

Tags: scale

Hello everyone please look at the picture when I scale the shield in top view(constrains to X axle) the front view was also changed, is there any ways the scale only limits in top view but not changing everything in other views?

Thank you 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select the vertices, edges or faces you want to scale
use axle restrictions.

### press to individually restrict:

- <kbd>x</kbd>
- <kbd>Y</kbd>
- <kbd>z</kbd>

### If you wish to restrict 2 axes, press:

- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to scale in X, Y, and restrict Z
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to scale in Y, Z, and and restrict X
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> to scale in X, Z, and restrict Y

[image: Example]
[image]